# Descendientes de categoria en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relaciones

Tengo una duda que creo q es simple, pero no sé como resolverla.

Tengo en mi aplicación, en el modelo categoría, lo siguiente:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this -> hasMany(Category::Class, 'parent_id');
}

public function descendants()
{
    return $this -> children() -> with('descendants');
}
```

A partir de esto, ya tengo todos los descendientes, pero no sé cómo hacer para traer todos los ID de los descendientes en mi componente.

Yo hice lo siguiente:

```
$subcats = array();
foreach ($this -> category -> descendants as $sc) {
     $subcats[] = $sc -> id;
}
```

Con esto me trae solo los ID de los descendientes directos, pero yo quiero obtener los de los hijos, los hijos de los hijos, y así sucesivamente.

¡Espero me puedan ayudar!

Comment: Como son las relaciones de las tablas y las tablas?

Comment: @adrigo en la tabla categories tengo una columna parent_id

Comment: Entonces entiendo que si yo estoy en la tabla categories, mi parent_id seria el de mi padre, y el de mi padre el de mi abuelo, ¿cierto? Entonces entiendo que tu quieres conseguir desde mi abuelo los ids de mi padre y mio, ¿no?

Comment: @adrigo Al revés. Yo tengo el id del padre, y lo que necesito es obtener los id de los hijos, nietos, bisnietos, etc.

Comment: Llevo todo el dia pensando y he estado comentando con amigos y compañeros.. creemos que computacionalmente esto que planteas supondria demasiado... La unica opcion que veo es plantearlo de alguna otra manera, como tener dos tablas, una que almacene las personas y otra que tenga parent_id y son_id en la que se almancenen los ids de la otra tabla. Solo es un ejemplo  que planteo, podrias pensar alguna otra forma. La forma que tu planteas supondrai tener un bucle constante mirando cuales son los id y una vez encuentres el del hijo vuelta a empezar....

Comment: @adrigo Claro...en la vista lo hago con un archivo partial que se llama a si mismo si encuentra hijos y de esta manera crea sólo el árbol de descendientes. Acá yo tengo esa idea, pero no se me ocurre cómo hacerlo en el componente.